# How to rename a file and preserve creation date in Python

Tags: python, filesystems

I know that the creation date isn't stored in the filesystem itself, but I'm encountering the problem that when I use `os.rename`, it's updating the creation date of the files I'm working with.

Is it possible to rename a file without changing its original creation date?

Comment: On which platform and with which file system?

Comment: Do you that the modification time (`st_mtime` in a `struct stat`) gets modified? Or `st_ctime`? Or something else?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As said by Tudor you can use [os.stat()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat) and [os.utime()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.utime).

```
stat = os.stat(myfile)
# your code - rename access and modify your file
os.utime(my_new_file, (stat.st_atime, stat.st_mtime))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can read the timestamp before modifying it with [`os.stat()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat), keep it in som variable, rename the file, then change newfile's timestamp to the held value with [`os.utime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.utime)